# Configure the time of 2 VMs to be same in millisecond accurancy

Tags: time, cloud, clock

Is there any way to configure via ssh two VMs to have the same date and time in a millisecond accurancy?

How can i do this?

Comment: In what way is this question related to the VMS family or operating systems (`vms` tag)?

Comment: I have a vms tag,dont i?

Comment: `vms` tag description: "VMS is any operating system of the VMS family:  OpenVMS, VAX/VMS, VAX-11/VMS, and VAX/VMS which run on the VAX, Alpha, and Itanium-based families of computers."